# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: Facebook Audience Network (help needed!)

Tags: facebook, xcode4, facebook-audience-network

I've read close to 50 threads on here, regarding linking frameworks to an Xcode project, but I've yet to find one that covers an issue I'm having with Facebook's Audience Network framework.

I'm using Xcode 4.2.3 (I'm on an old mac with OS X Lion - don't ask!), building for iOS 6.1, using Facebook SDK 3.2.1.

I'm trying to test banner ad formats within specific view controllers, however, getting an error every time I build the code, based exactly on the tutorials, even Facebook's sample code isn't compiling. I've added `FBAudienceNetwork.framework` to almost every folder on my machine, added via dragging and dropping, and via the Link Binary with Libraries option. I've tried to changing the Framework Search paths, to no avail.

I'm using the following frameworks: AdSupport, StoreKit, CoreMotion, UIKit, Foundation, CoreGraphics

Getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAShapeLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdChoicesView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransaction", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)
      objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdMediumRectangleView.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)
  "_kCATransactionDisableActions", referenced from:
      -[FBAdMediumRectangleView updateViewForSize:view:] in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdMediumRectangleView.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Added in Quartzcore.framework, and errors now reduced to;

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've made Foundation.framework optional. Build settings armv7, armv7s, iOS 6.1, Simulator only. Build Active Architecture ONLY Yes/No.

Comment: Do you receive these errors when running on both the simulator and device? Have you checked that the framework is included in the project? Check TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> Link Binaries with Libraries -> FacebookAudienceNetwork.framework. Which iOS version are you running this on?

Comment: I'm only running this on a simulator at the moment. Build settings; armv7 armv7s ; Build Active Architecture Yes/No. All Framework's are included within the project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a software engineer on the Audience Network team at Facebook, and I have some suggestions that may help.

Try adding "QuartzCore.framework" to your target. That should resolve the _OBJC_CLASS_$_CA* linker errors. Classes with a "CA" prefix are part of QuartzCore/Core Animation.

If the "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSession" error still appears, try weak-linking the Foundation framework by setting the "Foundation.framework" to "optional" in Build Phases, Link Binary With Libraries.

You should be able to successfully build after those steps. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Erika,

Thanks for your help. 

I've added QuartzCore.framework to the project, and that's cleared up the three CA* linker errors, however the NSURLSessio error still appears. 

I've weak-linked the Foundation framework but the error still appears;

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURLSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any other suggestions?
Thanks again!

Comment: I wasn't able to find a good solution to this without significant downsides. Try using the version of Audience Network included with SDK 3.19 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads).

Comment: SDK 3.23.1 has just been released, which includes a fix for this. Try it out, and let me know!

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLSession` was added in iOS 7.0. Any improper reference to it in your app will cause this problem when ran on a device with iOS 6.0. You need to use proper techniques to ensure the class is never referenced under iOS 6.0 or make your deployment target iOS 7.0.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Given I'm on a mac with OS X Lion, and thus can't upgrade to Xcode 5 or higher (which supports building to iOS 7.0) - Any suggestions as to how I may potentially go about making sure the class is never referenced?